# The apex trigger function .addError() on AfterUpdate is not working for my code

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I am trying to create an exception in facility cloud salesforce, when the occupied area of a building is greater than total area. There is no error in the code, but the code is not working. I am not getting any exception.

The complete code

```
public with sharing class FacilityDistributionAreaTriggerHandler  {
    public class MyOwnException extends Exception{}
    
    
    public static void recalcFacilities(List<Facility_Distribution_Area__c> newList, Map<Id, Facility_Distribution_Area__c> oldMap, Set<Id> facilityIds)  {
        if (facilityIds == null || facilityIds.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
      Map<Id, Facility__c> facilitiesToUpdate = new Map<Id, Facility__c>();
        List<AggregateResult> aggregatedResults = [SELECT 
                                        Facility__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Office_Area_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Office_Area_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Production_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Production_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Rd_Lab_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Rd_Lab_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Others_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Others_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Warehouse_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Warehouse_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                        , sum(Facility_Distribution_Area__c.Occupied_Greenhouse_By_Division_Sqm__c) Occupied_Greenhouse_By_Division_Sqm__c
                                    FROM Facility_Distribution_Area__c where Facility__c IN :facilityIds group by Facility__c
                                    ];

        List<Facility__c> areacheck  = [SELECT 
                                   Vacant_Office_Area__c
                                   ,Vacant_Production_Area__c
                                   ,Vacant_RD_Lab_Area__c
                                   ,Vacant_Others_Area__c
                                   ,Vacant_Warehouse_Area__c
                                   ,Vacant_Greenhouse_Area__c
                                   , Total_Office_Area__c
                                    , Total_Production_Area__c
                                    ,Total_RD_Lab_Area__c
                                    , Total_Others_Area__c
                                    , Total_Warehouse_Area__c
                                    , Total_Greenhouse_Area__c
                                FROM Facility__c WHERE Id IN:facilityIds
                                ];
         Map<Id, Facility__c> area = new Map<Id, Facility__c>(areacheck);    
         Map<Id, Facility__c> facilityIDtoErrorMessage = new Map<Id, Facility__c>(areacheck);  

For (Facility_Distribution_Area__c fda : newList){
   if(facilityIdToErrorMessage.containsKey(fda.Facility__c)) {
      fda.addError('Invalid');
   }
}
             
        for (AggregateResult res : aggregatedResults) {
            //id=(Id)res.get('Facility__c');
            Facility__c f = area.get((Id)res.get('Facility__c'));
            //f.Id = (Id)res.get('Facility__c');
            f.Occupied_Office_Area__c     = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Office_Area_By_Division_Sqm__c'); 
            f.Occupied_Production_Area__c = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Production_By_Division_Sqm__c'); 
            f.Occupied_RD_Lab_Area__c     = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Rd_Lab_By_Division_Sqm__c'); 
            f.Occupied_Others_Area__c     = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Others_By_Division_Sqm__c'); 
            f.Occupied_Warehouse_Area__c  = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Warehouse_By_Division_Sqm__c'); 
            f.Occupied_Greenhouse_Area__c = (Decimal)res.get('Occupied_Greenhouse_By_Division_Sqm__c');  
            if(f.Total_Office_Area__c< f.Occupied_Office_Area__c)
                 { facilityIDToErrorMessage.put(f.Id,'Invalid');
            }
            else if(f.Total_Production_Area__c< f.Occupied_Production_Area__c)
                    {facilityIDToErrorMessage.put(f.Id,'Invalid');
                }
            else if(f.Total_RD_Lab_Area__c< f.Occupied_RD_Lab_Area__c)
                  {facilityIDToErrorMessage.put(f.Id,'Invalid');
                } 
            else {facilitiesToUpdate.put(f.Id,f);
            }

      
        System.debug('--- newList:'+newList);
        System.debug('--- newList:'+newList.size());
       
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddError` in a trigger context only works when applied directly onto the records in the trigger.

So you need to add the error to Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap (unless you're in a delete trigger, in which case you use Trigger.old or Trigger.oldMap).

I can't see the exact Object on which your trigger is running. I'm assuming it's on a child record of Facility? In that case you need to add the errors to those records (and not to the Facility).

The way to then add the errors to the records is:

- build a Map<Id,String> facilityIDToErrorMessage of errors messages for each of the Facility__c records. This map you fill while looping through the Aggregateresults so instead of `f.addError('xxx')` you do `facilityIDToErrorMessage.put(f.Id,'xxx')`
- re-loop through the List<Facility_Distribution_Area__c> newList (if this is the original Trigger.New from the trigger) and then check if that Distribution Area's Facility's Id is in the error map. Something like

`

```
For (Facility_Distribution_Area__c fda : newList){
   if(facilityIdToErrorMessage.containsKey(fda.Facility__c)) {
      fda.addError([theErrorMessage])
   };
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the response. Could you explain me more about "build a Map<Id,String> of errors messages for each of the Facility__c records"? What do you mean by Map of error messages ?

Comment: I've put some additional info in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Clairbois, I have modified the code like like this, `facilityIDToErrorMessage.put(f.Id,f)`
But it still does not work.

Comment: I'm posting it as an answer now, I'll delete it later.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question, that will work better with stackexchange. Anyway, I can't really judge this because the code is not complete. The trigger itself is not there and also the loop through the trigger.new list is not in your reply. Could you update all of that in your question?

Comment: Hi. You still did not include the actual trigger so it's still hard to judge but what I can see is that you have to split the loop through Aggregate results from the loop through trigger variables. So the .addError really needs to happen in a loop through a list of Trigger variable (i.e. Trigger.New or Trigger.NewMap) otherwise it doesn't work.